# Data export from app on app exchange

Tags: apex, visualforce, app, data-export, csv

I have a SFDC App which does data (Account, Contact, Lead) segmentation and flags them according to segmentation rules. I want to be able to provide a link on visualforce page to download certain accounts/contacts/leads (according to flag) in csv/excel(whichever is easy to do) format. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following for your purpose

```
<!-- Your Main Page -->
<apex:page controller="DownloadData">
<apex:form >
<apex:commandButton value="DownloadRecords" action="{!records}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

<!-- -Your DownloadDemo Page- -->
<apex:page controller="DownloadData"  contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#FileName.xls" >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!data}" var="d">
<apex:column value="{!d.ID}"/>
<apex:column value="{!d.Data__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>


/*****Same Controller for both the classes*****/
 public with sharing class DownloadData {

public PageReference records() 
{
   return new PageReference('/apex/DownloadDemo');
}

public List<MyObject__c> getData() {

    List<MyObject__c> mo = [SELECT ID,Data__C FROM MyObject__c];

    return mo;
}}
```